# Can't work out download URL

Tags: html, url, download

I can't seem to work out the download URL of the CSV file on [this webpage](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cat=0-13&date=today%207-d&cmpt=q), all I can workout is this:

```
<div id="exportMI" class="settings-menu-item goog-menuitem ">Download as CSV</div><div class="settings-menu-item goog-submenu">
```

Doesn't seem very useful, can you help me get the download url?

Comment: If you have Chrome: Download the file and press Shift-CTRL-J to bring up the Downloads page (or use the Window menu). The download URL is shown there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your browser's download manager to find out the download URL, which is http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?cmpt=q&content=1&export=1